# VB Crashes with no indication

Tags: visual-studio, vba, vb6, basic

As the code down below, I declared a dll to use its function, which returns 0 when succeed, else when it isn't.

I need the width,height,stride,leng,bytes generates from the function, so I used ByRef to declare them. it works well when I start it, but after it shows 3 msgbox, visual basic crashes.

I just started vb 2 days ago, and I know it must be a rookie question, but I don't even know what the problem is, so... help me guys.

Anything confuses you guys please tell me, I'll correct it at once.

This is the documentary for the DLL

sn  Char

width   int (IN/OUT)

height  Int (IN/OUT)

bytes   char* (IN/OUT)

stride  int(IN/OUT)

len int(IN/OUT)

```
Private Declare Function Ict_WMK_ISV Lib "C:\acd.dll" (ByVal PrinterModel As String, ByRef width As Long, ByRef height As Long, ByRef bytes As Variant, ByRef stride As Long, ByRef leng As Long) As Integer

Private Sub Command1_Click()

'Ict_WMK_ISV (Fax)

Dim width As Long
Dim height As Long
Dim stride As Long
Dim leng As Long
Dim bytes As Variant
Dim printmodel As String

Dim iResult As Integer

printmodel = "Samsung SCX-6x45 Series PCL6"

If IsNull(bytes) Then
  MsgBox ("null")
Else
  MsgBox ("not null")
End If

bytes = Empty


iResult = Ict_WMK_ISV(printmodel, width, height, bytes, stride, leng)


MsgBox (Str(iResult))

End Sub
```

Comment: For the code 'bytes = Empty' is 'Empty' a variable declared elsewhere. I cannot see it as  a VB keyword here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd409611.aspx

Comment: Are you getting any error messages at all?

Comment: Try adding a simple error handler (see [here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/error-handling) - just do the `on error goto`, the label, and `Msgbox(err.message)`)

Comment: It is unlikely that `bytes` is a `Variant`, and it is more common that the return type would be a `Long` instead of an `Integer`.  But without documenetation on the function `Ict_WMK_ISV`then these are guesses.  Did the dll come with documentation or a header file?

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code module.

Comment: We also have `err.lastdllerror`. Note you have to `On Error Resume Next` to use this. The LastDLLError property applies only to DLL calls made from Visual Basic code. When such a call is made, the called function usually returns a code indicating success or failure, and the LastDLLError property is filled. Check the documentation for the DLL's functions to determine the return values that indicate success or failure. Whenever the failure code is returned, the Visual Basic application should immediately check the LastDLLError property. See API call SetLastError for details.

Comment: Tried 'On Error goto','On Error Resume Next'. Nothing changes.
bytes can be declared as Empty, I typed empty and it automatically changed to Empty. 'Option Explicit' also changes nothing

Comment: You need to messagebox out the value of `err.lastdllerror` after calling your function. `On Error Resume Next` prevents VB from crashing (not that it actually does on dll errors) on errors so messagebox gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Then run it under windbg (Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install theWindows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called Symbols in C:\

Start Windbg. File menu - Symbol File Path and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2006/08/30/731150.aspx

```
How to generate symbol files for Visual Basic 6.0

In VB6, symbols are not created by default. To create symbols for your VB6 applications, follow these steps:

•Open the source code for your project.

•Select "<projectname> Properties" from the Project menu.

•In the Compile tab, check Create Symbolic Debug Info and select No Optimizations

•Recompile. This will create a .PDB file (the symbols) in the same directory as your .DLL / .EXE / .OCX file.

•Note: This does *not* break binary compatibility.
```

(if you set the environmental variable `link=/pdb:none` the symbols are stored in the compiled file)

When it crashes you can get the exception info.